# Keras specification of y

Tags: keras

I am trying to understand the following snippets from Keras documentation. What is the logic of specifying y as Dense statement followed by '(x)'? Not sure about the purpose of this statement.

```
# this is a logistic regression in Keras
x = Input(shape=(32,))
y = Dense(16, activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(x, y)
```

Comment: x is not input data, it is simply the shape and structure of expected input. y is the output given that input structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite simple, in this case `y` is the output of a Dense layer with 16 units and a softmax activation, given the input `x`.

This structure is meant to be functional-like, so you can specify models with multiple inputs and outputs easily in code.